# How can I calculate points on a circular path? (Center known)

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas

I'm currently working on a small HTML canvas game (zero point of the canvas top-left). I need the coordinates (X,Y) on a circle.

The radius and the center are known.

My variables:

```
var radius = 50;
var center_x = 200;
var center_y = 200;
var angle = 45;
```

Answer (score 2):

The formula for a point on a circle, given the angle, is:

x = x<sub>center</sub> + r·cos()
      y = y<sub>center</sub> + r·sin()

...where  is the angle in radians.

Since on a web page the Y coordinate is downwards, you would subtract the term in the formula.

Here is a demo, where the angle changes continually:

```js
var radius = 50;
var center_x = 100;
var center_y = 100;
var angle = 50; // Will change in this demo

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const span = document.querySelector("span");
const loop = () => {
    angle = (angle + 1) % 360;

    // Formula:
    var rad = angle * Math.PI / 180;
    var x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(rad);
    var y = center_y - radius * Math.sin(rad);

    // Draw point
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff2626";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    
    // Display angle
    span.textContent = angle;

    // Repeat at next paint cycle
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
loop();
```

```html
<div>Angle: <span></span></div>
<canvas width=500 height=160></canvas>
```